# Unable to connect to Raspberry Pi via router

Tags: wifi, ping

I set up the Raspberry Pi with a connection to my router and it shows that it is connected with tooltip:

```
wlan0: Associated with <ssid>
wlan0: Configured 192.168.1.<N>/24
eth0: Link is down
docker0: Link is down
```

From my machine, pinging to `raspberrypi.local` returns nothing (10 minutes ago it returned the IP) and an SSH connection does nothing or throws an error.

I checked that both machines are connected to the internet.

```
$ ping raspberrypi.local
ping: cannot resolve raspberrypi.local: Unknown host
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/rpi pi@192.168.1.<N>
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.<N> port 22: Operation timed out 
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/rpi pi@192.168.1.<N>
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.<N> port 22: No route to host
```

Answer (score 2):

The raspberry Pi showed a connection for longer than it was connected. When I
tried again, it was no longer connected and could no longer connect to the
router. The connection between the Pi and the router was across a courtyard and possibly heavy rainfall had disturbed the 5G connection, as [this site](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/can-weather-affect-wi-fi) mentions:

> The weather condition that has the greatest effect on a Wi-Fi signal is
>   rainfall, particularly for wireless setups using the 2.4-GHz radio
>   frequency. Water droplets absorb this radio frequency and partially block the
>   signal. Anecdotal evidence from communities with light-pole-based public Wi-Fi
>   suggest that rainy days had an impact on signal strength. Even so, Wi-Fi
>   signals are short range and usually deployed indoors. While rainfall can
>   create interference -- in much the same way that it limits visibility for
>   human eyes -- attenuation due to distance from the router is a much likelier
>   culprit for low signal strength.

I restarted the Pi and it worked. I could have also moved it closer to the router or used an ethernet connection.